# My javascript validation of number function does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, validation

```
function ValidateShippedQuantity() {
    var shippedQty = jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val();
    shippedQty = shippedQty.toString();
    for (i = 0; i < shippedQty.length; i++) {
        var c = shippedQty.charAt(i);
        if (isNaN(c)) //(!(/^\d+$/.test(shippedQty))) 
        {
            alert("Only Numeric Values Allowed");
            //x.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I want is to check the textbox that contains only numeric value. And the function above either isNaN or /^\d+$/.test() does not work since it always returns false whatever I enter such as "1" or "10".
Even weird, the isNaN used to work for a while. And then it just did not work later no matter what I undid what I did.

The button which called the validation function, is within a Gridview.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdTrk" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"
    OnClientClick="javascript:return ValidateShippedQuantity();" CausesValidation="false" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

The textbox of txtShippedQuantity,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipped&nbsp;Qty">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblShippedQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShippedQuantity")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtShippedQuantity" Width="50px" Text='<%#Eval("ShippedQuantity")%>' />
   </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**For those who has the same problem, the answer or solution is below.**
This is the real happiness of solving the problem yourself after disappointing procedure. 
@cymen gives me a little help. And I change one line to his codes.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnUpdTrk').on('click', ValidateShippedQuantity);
        });
        function ValidateShippedQuantity() {
        var shippedQty = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTrkInfo_txtShippedQuantity_0').value;
        var shippedQtyNumber = parseInt(shippedQty, 10);
        if (shippedQtyNumber.toString() !== shippedQty) {
            alert("Only Numeric Values Allowed for Tracking #.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**The second line from @cymen codes, is the cause of problem for my aspx page, at least after editing that I got what I wanted. I think it's the getTlementById part. After finding the correct ID for txtbox txtShippedQuantity from the google chrome developer tool.**

Comment: I believe the line should be var c = shippedQty.charAt(i);
        if (isNaN(c))

Comment: @BradM it's a typo. changed.thanks.

Comment: No need to test each character, just need `return /^\d+$/.test(jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to parse the input string to number and then compare the number to the original string:

```
var input = '5';
var number = parseInt(input, 10);
if (number.toString() === input) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

So I would write you function as:

```
function ValidateShippedQuantity() {
    var shippedQty = jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val();
    var shippedQtyNumber = parseInt(shippedQty, 10);
    if (shippedQtyNumber.toString() !== shippedQty) {
        alert("Only Numeric Values Allowed");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is a functioning demo (with additional alert on valid): http://jsfiddle.net/S4CQT/

Note that this will fail if they enter 1,000 as it will check if '1000' equals '1,000'. So if you want to support commas, you have a couple of options but a quick way (that would consider 10,00 to be valid), would be to change the statement in the if to this:

```
shippedQtyNumber.toString() !== shippedQty.replace(',', '')
```

Another potential failure is if you allow non-whole numbers (like 10.5). In that case, look into [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: thanks. it's whole numbers. and i tried your codes which has the same issue. no luck.

Comment: There is a problem with how you are hooking it up then. Here is a jsfiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/S4CQT/

Comment: yeah. i added more details above.

Comment: i still do not know why clearly. but i fix the problem. see my problem description above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ASP.NET validators

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^\d+$" 
    ControlToValidate="txtShippedQuantity" runat="server" 
    Text="Must be a number" Color="Red" Display="Dynamic" />
```

This will prevent a postback client side if it does not match the specified regular expression.

Alternatively, you can use the RangeValidator

```
<asp:RangeValidator 
    MinimumValue='<%# Int32.MinValue %>' 
    MaximumValue='<%# Int32.MaxValue %>' 
    ControlToValidate="txtShippedQuantity" 
    runat="server" />
```

Comment: This should be a suggestion, since it is a workaround (a fine one)

Comment: How is it a workaround? It's the standardized built-in way to validate controls in ASP.NET

Comment: The question is about the JS, you can workaround having to write your own JS by using ASP.NET validators

Comment: i tried your way.but this does not work with my codes. the validation should be triggered after a linkbutton is pressed. that's why i used javascript to stop the action before taking effect.

Comment: The question is also tagged as ASP.NET, meaning the standardized ASP.NET way is a valid answer.

Comment: I disagree, the question is about the JS, what you suggested is probably a better way to solve the problem, but it's not an aswer to the 'question' "My javascript validation of number function does not work correctly"

Comment: @JuanMendes We will have to agree to disagree then. From my perspective a functioning solution is the #1 priority so long as it remains within the confines of the language and environment requirements. By tagging the question as ASP.NET, the asker informs us that ASP.NET-based solutions are valid as well. If he did not want this, it should not be tagged as ASP.NET.

Comment: @user2096925 Is there a particular requirement for the validation to not be live?

Comment: @Syddraf what do u mean by not be live?

Comment: @user2096925 ASP.NET validators effectively validate when the textbox is changed. As a user types into the box, it will validate the data in the box and, in the sample I gave, display "Must be a number" whenever it is invalid.

Comment: @Syddraf well it's not real-time validation. after moving the focus out of the textbox, it shows up the Text which is too late since the linkbutton may be pressed down as "Must be a number" shows up.

Comment: @user2096925 The validator will still prevent a postback if the text is invalid. Or is your LinkButton using AJAX to submit the data?

Comment: @Syddraf it's not ajax. i added some details and u can see them now.

Answer (score 0):

Um, shouldn't

```
if (isNaN(shippedQty))
```

be

```
if (isNaN(c))
```

And why are you looping when a regular expression can check for numbers?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4nXT3/

```
function ValidateShippedQuantity() {
    var shippedQty = jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val();
    if (isNaN(shippedQty)) {
        alert('Only Numeric Values Allowed');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Update**: read the comments to know why this bad.

Comment: `isNaN()` called on a string is never going to return true, you proably meant `isNan(parseInt(shippedQty), 10)`

Comment: In Chrome console, isNaN("10a") -> true

Comment: I stand corrected. But I'm reluctant to upvote because it seems that isNaN() does return a lot of false positives, and should be avoided https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNan "The next version of ECMAScript (ES6) contains the function `Number.isNaN`... a reliable way to test whether x is NaN or not... as the result is not subject to the false positives that make isNaN unreliable.

Comment: This is another example from the MDN page: "This is a false positive and the reason why isNaN is not entirely reliable"`isNaN("blabla") => true` "blabla" is converted to a number. Parsing this as a number fails and returns NaN"

Comment: That's good; that's the desired behavior for his purposes. The one that's troubling is `isNaN('  ')` -> `false`.

Comment: Yes, but you're relying on behavior that is at the very least confusing, at worst, just plain wrong, a string is not `NaN`. And you'll have to work around the spaces case that converts into a `0` because of that bad definition of isNaN. You should at least check that case in your solution

Comment: Good point. But if you think of `isNaN` as "isn't a number", then it reads right! :) Not future proof though, and probably not a great way to go, I agree. Thinking about downvoting myself.

Comment: I was going to say closing it is a better option, but this is such good warning that it should stay up

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below approach, that said I don't see anything wrong with your approach to validate this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateShippedQuantity() { 
    var shippedQty = jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val(); //alert(shippedQty);
    shippedQty = shippedQty.toString();
    for (i = 0; i < shippedQty.length; i++) {
        var c = shippedQty.charAt(i);
        if (isNaN(c))         {
            alert("Only Numeric Values Allowed");
            //x.focus();
            return false;
        }

    }
    if(shippedQty.length == 0)
        {
            alert("Field can't be blank");
        }
    return true;
    $("form").submit();
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="txtShippedQuantity" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" onclick="ValidateShippedQuantity()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you are making the mistake by not being able to call the function properly.

I have added a demo too at [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Prfec/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateShippedQuantity() {
    var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
    return reg.test(jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is something that tests if all the characters are digits. No need to loop through each character, just use regular expressions http://jsfiddle.net/4nXT3/ This will not be as easy if you need to support floats or other input formats, in which case you need something more complicated [like what was suggested by Cymen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011038/my-javascript-validation-of-number-function-does-not-work-correctly/15011645#answer-15011105)

```
function ValidateShippedQuantity() 
    var input = jQuery("#txtShippedQuantity").val();
    if ( !/^\d+$/.test(input) )  {
        alert('Only Numeric Values allowed')
        return false;
    }
    return true
}
```